# Rails & Refinery CMS: Determine the Controller class name from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, refinerycms

I'm working with an existing Refinery CMS app for a client that has many controllers in many different places. If you are n00b to Refinery CMS, you can nest entire rails apps INSIDE the vender folder and they act like plugins. Its complex how it works and even worse a lot of the models/controllers are embedded in the refinery gem so a controller might exist but theres not file for it.

I wanted to extend a controller by following this example:

http://refinerycms.com/edge-guides/extending-controllers-and-models-with-decorators

which I did but my code was not firing. I did actually fix this so my problem is solved but in the future it would be useful to know what controller called this view I have. The view is tucked away in the gem HOWEVER a partial that it references was already overridden so I could throw something like:

```
<%= raise self.class.to_yaml %>
```

The problem with this I get the following error:

```
can't dump anonymous class: #<Class:0x000000061f5850>
```

Which isn't very helpful.

**My question is this:** How can I output the class name of the controller that calls any given view/partial ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `params[:controller]`
And `params[:action]` for current action

Comment: thanks! Also, I think this might be a better answer `params[:controller].camelize` because my problem was that I missed the fact that I needed to add `::Admin` in the middle.

Comment: DO you have your controller placed in .../admin/users_controller.rb and want to get rezult like "...::Admin::Users ?

Comment: yeah I ended up needing to override the controller instead of extending it due to needing to customize one of the restful methods. I found this  page that helped me figure out what file to override (see rails command for how to do this on this page): https://gist.github.com/ryandeussing/2502881